# Creating Dynamic open Graph tags using PHP

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I am new to PHP and I want to create a dynamic open graph tag to my blog page. I am using a single header.php for all my blog posts/pages and I want to be able to create a dynamic open graph tag that can pull the details (url, title, description and image) from my sql database. Can somebody please write me a code that can do exactly what I wanted. Thanks in advance.

Done a lot of researching online and couldn’t get a proper solution.